# Update button not doing anything in Rails Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have the typical two form setup in my rails app, one for create and one for edit/update. My create form works perfectly but for some reason my update form button doesn't do anything. On click nothing happens as if the button has been deactivated or something. My assumption is that there so something wonky happening with Javascript but I can't find anything that will be causing this. I have also thought maybe there is a missing closing html element but thats also not the case for I have a RubyMine which detects these. I've been stuck on this for hours!

Form on index page:

#### index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@suggested_invite, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="mynewsuggestedinvite" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Suggested Invite</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mynewsuggestedinviteclose">Close</button>
              <%= submit_tag "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

#### _suggested_invite.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(suggested_invite, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
     <div class="modal fade" id="myupdatesuggestedinvite_<%= suggested_invite.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" id="myupdatebutton_<%= suggested_invite.id %>" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
 <% end %>
```

#### dashboard.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".city").on("change keyup", function() {
        var city = $(this).val()
        $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+encodeURIComponent(city), function(val) {
            if(val.results.length) {
                var location = val.results[0].geometry.location
                $(".lat").val(location.lat)
                $(".lon").val(location.lng)
            }
        })
    })
    function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $(".imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function ()
    {
        var input = $('#'+this.id + ' .city')[0];
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load');
    });

    $('#mynewsuggestedinvite').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#mynewsuggestedinvite .form-control').val('');
        $('#mynewsuggestedinvite .imgInp').val('');
        $('#mynewsuggestedinvite .blah').attr("src", "placeholder-image.png");
    });

    $(function () {
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                $(".card-image").val($(this).val());
            }else{
                $(this).css('color', 'transparent');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Both the index and _suggested_invite partial share the same javascript file. I know the JS file works fine because the create form in the index file works perfectly. I am so lost please let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

#### Edit

I added an onClick event handler and when clicking on the button the event is initiated. I am now more confused than ever.

Comment: Check the network tab on your developer tools, `remote: true` means you are using AJAX, and the ajax call might be returning an error

Answer (score 0):

Change `submit_tag` to `f.submit`

```
<%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It doesn't work still. No errors or anything so I don't know what else to say other than your proposed solution doesn't work.

Comment: I really think it has something to do with javascript or something but I can't figure out where?